# How to pass jQuery Ajax value to radio button group

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I used jquery ajax code for get some values for running page.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#store_select").autocomplete({
            source: "load_store_list.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('.outlettype').val(ui.item.outlettype);
            }
        });
    });
   </script>
```

I want to set that passed value to radio button group how to do it

eg: think ajax code passed "Car" as a value, I want to make checked for that value

```
<input type="radio" name="veh" value="Car"/>Car
<input type="radio" name="veh" value="Bus"/>Bus
```

Comment: So do you have a question to ask or is this just a wishlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.prop('checked', 'checked')` with attribute selector `[value=Car]`

```
$('input[type=radio][value=Car]').prop('checked', 'checked');
```

**Edit**

```
$(function () {
    $("#store_select").autocomplete({
        source: "load_store_list.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('.outlettype').val(ui.item.outlettype);
            $('input[type=radio][value=' + ui.item.outlettype + ']').prop('checked', 'checked');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What does setting the value have to do with it being checked?

Comment: @RUJordan I didnt get  you. OP wants to check the checkbox with value car

Comment: "I want to set that passed value to radio button group how to do it"

Comment: Yes, but as passed from the AJAX request, not hard coded as in your example.